# Getting unexpected result while sorting with null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that contains values like this:

```
var testSorting = [0,null,1,0,1,null];
```

When I sort it like this:

```
testSorting.sort()
```

then the output is `[0, 0, 1, 1, null, null]`

But if I do it like this:

```
testSorting.sort(function(a, b){
    return a-b;
});
console.log(testSorting);
```

the output is `[0, null, 0, null, 1, 1]`.

I don't know why the result is like this. I need the result to be like the first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` coerces to `0` in math operations and to a string `"null"` in `.toString()` operation, which is what happens when you don't provide a callback.

So in the first code, it's as though you're sorting this:

```
['0','null','1','0','1','null']
```

And in the second, it's as though you're sorting this:

```
[0,0,1,0,1,0];
```

If you need it to be like the first, then you need to make sure that the `a===null` values always return a value higher than the other numbers and the `b===null` values always return one lower.

```js
var testSorting = [0,null,1,0,1,null];

testSorting.sort(function(a, b){
    return a === null ? Infinity :
           b === null ? -Infinity :
                        a - b;
});
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(testSorting, 2, null);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```